NGINX IMAP proxy and real IP of client
There is such a configuration for nginx/1.24.0 (--with-http_realip_module) as an example of an IMAP proxy protocol. But there is a problem with getting the real IP address of the client in the nginx logs (80_access.log). And there is a problem with getting the real IP address of the client in index.php in the variable $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].
user www;
worker_processes auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;

events {
    use kqueue;
    worker_connections 10240;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status "$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-error.log warn;

    keepalive_timeout 30;
    keepalive_requests 200;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name imap.example.com;

        server_name_in_redirect on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/gatewaymail.net/imap/80_access.log common;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/gatewaymail.net/imap/80_errors.log warn;

        root /usr/local/www/nginx/imap;
        index index.php;

        location / {
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/imap-php8.3-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 1024k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 1024k;

            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

            fastcgi_param SERVER_ADMIN support@gatewaymail.net;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_SIGNATURE nginx/$nginx_version;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

    }

}

mail {

    proxy_pass_error_message  on;

    server {
        auth_http imap.example.com/index.php;
        listen 143;
        protocol imap;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/gatewaymail.net/imap/imap_proxy_errors.log warn;

    }
}

In the logs, I always see the internal or external IP of my own server depending on the configuration.
If:
server_name imap.example.com
auth_http imap.example.com/index.php

I see the external IP of my server.
If:
server_name imap;
auth_http imap/index.php;

I see the internal IP of my server.
I tried different configurations:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/
nginx mail proxy behind haproxy - get clients real ip address
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;

nothing helped.
I ask for help from the experts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090938/how-to-get-real-ip-of-visitor-if-our-app-is-behind-a-reverse-proxy

I'm confused about the IMAP portion of this? Is the Nginx as it relates to IMAP or HTTP/PHP?

@Chris Haas NGINX as proxy an IMAP and redirects everything to HTTP/PHP

Problem is solved, in PHP it receives a variable $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] which contains the real IP of the client.
